# How to check if user is authenticated in ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When a user logs in, he successfully gets a token.

How can I in the backend then check if he's authenticated when he refreshes the page?

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always seems to be true, even if the token has been removed from the session.

Comment: do you have the "authentication" field in your web.config?

Comment: Yeah but it is set to none. I did fix my problem by sending a request to /api/account/logout